# TypeScript won't resolve module when import is used

Tags: node.js, typescript, amd, commonjs, typescript1.4

```
// Modules/MyModule.ts --------------------------------
import fs = require("fs");

module Hello {
    export function World(): string {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}


// Main/App.ts ----------------------------------------
console.log(Hello.World()); // Cannot find name 'Hello'
```

For some reason this produces the error specified above. The weird thing is if I uncomment the import statement I don't get this error anymore. (it's not used anyway)

Both produce the same error:

`tsc Main/App.ts --module "commonjs"`

`tsc Main/App.ts --module "amd"`

Is this really a compiler bug or am I missing something. Do I need to specify external module requires somehow different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one comes up quite a lot - the key to joy and happiness in TypeScript is to choose *either* internal modules *or* external modules and not both.

I have written more extensively about [choosing between internal and external modules in TypeScript](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201505/Blog/Stop-Mixing-TypeScript-Internal-And-External-Modules/). The bottom line is choose only *one*.

In your case, you need to fully commit to external modules. Here is an updated example:

```
// Modules/Hello.ts --------------------------------
import fs = require("fs");

export function World(): string {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

The module name for the above file is `Hello`, because it is in a file named `Hello.ts`.

You can then use it like this...

```
// Main/App.ts ----------------------------------------
import Hello = require("./Modules/Hello");

console.log(Hello.World());
```

p.s. Node apps are compiled using `commonjs` mode - but this works for AMD too.

Comment: thank you, that solves my problem. It somehow makes sense now but on the other hand it sounds like inconsistency in the typescript specification

Comment: There does seem to be a bit of confusion around this - but the choice between internal and external modules is exclusive.